# Global facebook instance in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, load, global

I would like to have my app log users into facebook in a settings view and then save the information into userdefaults. When the app loads, it should log into facebook if the information is in userdefaults, and if not, continue operating normally without facebook functionality. Basically, I want one instance of facebook which is loaded at the beginning, and all the information used throughout every view in the app.

Is this possible?

Everything that I have seen so far shows one instance per view which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do it all the time in our apps.

I typically create a Facebook singleton to manage the Facebook interaction and store the token in either NSUserDefaults or the Keychain, depending on the application.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of what a singleton was until now.